# SQL Server search using like while ignoring blank spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-like

I have a `phone` column in the database, and the records contain unwanted spaces on the right. I tried to use  trim and replace, but it didn't return the correct results.

If I use

```
phone like '%2581254%'
```

it returns

```
 customerid
 -----------
 33470
 33472
 33473
 33474
```

but I need use  percent sign or wild card in the beginning only, I want to match the left side only.

So if I use it like this

```
 phone like '%2581254'
```

I get nothing, because of the spaces on the right!

So I tried to use  trim and replace, and I get one result only

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(phone)) LIKE '%2581254'
```

returns

```
 customerid
 -----------
 33474
```

Note that these four ids have same phone number!

Table data

```
customerid    phone
-------------------------------------
33470         96506217601532388254
33472         96506217601532388254
33473         96506217601532388254
33474         96506217601532388254  
33475         966508307940
```

I added many number for test propose

The php function takes last 7 digits and compare them.

For example

```
01532388254 will be 2581254
```

and I want to search for all users that has this 7 digits in their phone number
2581254

I can't figure out where's the problem!

It should return 4 ids instead of 1 id

Comment: Please post the table data in the question (especially phone number and datetype of the column)

Comment: Obviously, those three just contain 2581254, not end with it.

Comment: I added  the data i'm searching for

Comment: Is your PHP function taking the last 7 digits or is it taking white space plus digits up to 7 characters?  Trim whitespace before you insert it in your database.

Comment: no without any space or characters  I print the phone number using var_dump php:232:string '2581254' (length=7)  as you see there's no spaces

Comment: Then you probably have control characters in your column and John Cappelletti's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the sample data, I suspect you have **control characters** in your data.  For example char(13), char(10)

**To confirm this, just run the following**

```
Select customerid,phone
 From  YourTable
 Where CharIndex(CHAR(0),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(1),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(2),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(3),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(4),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(5),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(6),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(7),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(8),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(9),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(10),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(11),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(12),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(13),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(14),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(15),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(16),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(17),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(18),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(19),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(20),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(21),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(22),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(23),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(24),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(25),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(26),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(27),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(28),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(29),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(30),[phone])+CharIndex(CHAR(31),[phone])
      +CharIndex(CHAR(127),[phone]) >0
```

**If the Test Results are Positive**

The following UDF can be used to strip the control characters from your data via an update

```
Update YourTable Set Phone=[dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](Phone)
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    ;with  cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(C) As (Select Top (32) Char(Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1) From cte1 a,cte1 b)
    Select @S = Replace(@S,C,' ')
     From  cte2

    Return LTrim(RTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(@S,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')))
End
--Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael        '+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')  --Returns: Michael LastName
```

As promised (and nudged by Bill), the following is a little commentary on the UDF.

1. We pass a string that we want stripped of Control Characters
2. We create an ad-hoc tally table of ascii characters 0 - 31
3. We then run a global search-and-replace for each character in the
   tally-table.  Each character found will be replaced with a space
4. The final string is stripped of repeating spaces  (a little trick
   Gordon demonstrated several weeks ago - don't have the original
   link)

Comment: The query returned 3 instead of 4 records  33470
33472
33473
I don't think it would work, there're 100 phone at least added each day, also I think the database adds these spaces, because the column type is nchar   will your way works if I run it after each inserting?

Comment: @AhmadzIssa OK 3 of the 4 records have control characters.  The UDF is used to clean the data ... Run the update once, and then use the UDF as part of the incremental update/add

Comment: Thank you I used it like this SELECT customerid  FROM [ccctadm].[customer] WHERE [ccctadm].[udf-Str-Strip-Control](Phone) like '%2581254'

 and worked like a charm  I appreciate your help. I really don't understand anything from this function but it worked thanksss

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Happy it helped.  Ill add some commentary for the udf in a bit.

Comment: I'm writing as an SO reviewer because your answer has been flagged. Would you care to add that commentary now? :)

Comment: @BillBell To my shame it slipped my mind.  Can you elaborate on Flagged?

Comment: Yes, I know, this is a terrible lapse on your part. This answer was in a queue for its 'length and content'. Its length seems adequate, so the filter must have noticed something it didn't like about the content. Then I noticed that you had offered to write something more in a comment and I took the liberty of asking you to provide it. Say something nice to the SO software.

Comment: @BillBell all set