# RTRIM does not remove spaces at the end?

Tags: sql-server, trailing, character-trimming

I have used the Query:

```
    update Table
    set Seg = RTRIM(Seg)
```

This still doesn't remove the extra spaces at the end? I really need to remove this as I am doing vlookups in Excel and it is causing problems.

The datatype of Seg column is (nchar(10), null)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is a hidden character (Char(13), Char(10)) at the end instead?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Comment: yes Mark is correct, just tested..`create table #t
(
col1 nchar(100)
)

insert into #t
select 'abc              '+char(13)+Char(10)


select col1,RTRIM(col1) from #t`

Comment: "SELECT is not broken."

Answer (score 1):

You can right-trim an `NCHAR(X)` column all you want, values will always be the same length. Namely: `X`. The value will always be padded with spaces, so `RTRIM` is basically a no-op on a fixed width character column.

Also note that in string comparisons, trailing spaces are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

To  trim spaces from the end  you should use

UPDATE
    TableName
SET
    ColumnName = RTRIM(ColumnName)

if you want to trim all spaces then use this

UPDATE
    TableName
SET
    ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName))