# Why am I getting a value with spaces using LTRIM and RTRIM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the LTRIM and RTRIM functions to remove spaces isn't working as I expect:

Example:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM('TEST NAME  ')) 
RESULT = 'TEST NAME  ' DOES NOT WORK

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM('TEST NAME '))
RESULT = 'TEST NAME' IT WORKS
```

Comment: Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: Take a peek at the UDF here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Answer (score 4):

Probably you have some characters that are not spaces (tabs) or your string is ending with `carriage-return`/null-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Actually for me with SQL Server 2008 R2 it works perfectly for both of your examples.

Proof :

```
SELECT '"' + RTRIM(LTRIM('TEST NAME  ')) + '"'  
SELECT '"' + RTRIM(LTRIM('TEST NAME ')) + '"'
```

Will give "TEST NAME" as output for both.

Your real data probably contain something else than spaces but your sample does not illustrate that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample code to find any hidden chars in your string

```
-- The @position variable holds the position of the character currently  
-- being processed. The @nstring variable is the Unicode character   
-- string to process.  
DECLARE @position int, @nstring nvarchar(500);  
-- Initialize the current position variable to the first character in   
-- the string.  
SET @position = 1;  
-- Initialize the character string variable to the string to process.   
-- Notice that there is an N before the start of the string, which   
-- indicates that the data following the N is Unicode data.  
SET @nstring = N'TEST NAME  ';  
-- Print the character number of the position of the string you are at,   
-- the actual Unicode character you are processing, and the UNICODE   
-- value for this particular character.  
PRINT 'Character #' + ' ' + 'Unicode Character' + ' ' + 'UNICODE Value';  
WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@nstring)  
-- While these are still characters in the character string,  
   BEGIN;  
   SELECT @position,   
      CONVERT(varchar, SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)),  
      UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1));  
   SELECT @position = @position + 1;  
   END;
```

Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can remove control characters CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) using replace:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE('TEST NAME  ', CHAR(13), '')
                          ,CHAR(10), '')
                  )
            )
```