# SQL Server removing trailing spaces from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which holds string datatype. I don't understand why the number of character is still 10 after removing the spaces or is there something I am missing out?

```
select top(5)
    [SECOND OCCURANCE] as [Date 2],
    len([SECOND OCCURANCE]) as [CharDate2],
    len(REPLACE([SECOND OCCURANCE], ' ', '')) as [NewCharDate2],
    [Second Occurance] = case when len([SECOND OCCURANCE]) = 10 
                                 then(right(CONCAT('0', [SECOND OCCURANCE]), 11)) 
                                 else [SECOND OCCURANCE] 
                         end
from 
    UFO_MERGED
```

Output:

```
 Date 2     CharDate2   NewCharDate2    Second Occurance
 --------------------------------------------------------
 06/12/2008   10           10             006/12/2008
 11/28/2007   11           11             11/28/2007
 12/16/2005   11           11             12/16/2005
 04/09/2004   11           11             04/09/2004
 5/15/2006    10           10             05/15/2006
```

Comment: Is the datatype CHAR or VARCHAR ?

Comment: I believe this is because when the table was created the column was set to strore varchar of length 10. Because of the way sql sever stores information you are sent a string of length 10 regardless

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: varchar and its MS SQL Server

Comment: Remove the tag in the question for mysql. Also show the table schema.

Comment: Date 2 does consist of 10 characters...

Comment: OK the trailing character may not be a SPACE  ... could be a control character like char(10) or char(13) ...

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Comment: The **best** fix is to change the `Date2` column to a `datetime` type. **DON'T STORE DATES AS VARCHAR!** But for the problem here, I wonder: is `Date2` a `varchar(10)` or just a `char(10)`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it is actually varchar (11). I have uploaded this file into the server database through python. when I used varchar(10) it showed some error, so I used varchar(11) instead. I have tried converting date2 to datetime using convert(datetime,date2,101)

Comment: i get this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: I suggest pasting a value into a hex editor or text editor that will show special characters.

Comment: @AdamM.  That is not how varchar works

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn No need to use a hex editor, just SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(length), value)

Comment: **Typo alert:** it's an **occurrence** - not an "occurance" ....

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server a datatype of CHAR holds the number of characters regardless if they are filled or not. So a `CHAR(11)` will fill in spaces if the word is shorter than 11. If the column is VARCHAR(11), spaces will automatically be trimmed if the length of the string is shorter than the size of the column.

Considering the space is still showing up in the count, it is possible the value needs to be examined in binary.

Try this to see the binary values without a hex editor:

```
SELECT
 CONVERT(varbinary(11), [SECOND OCCURANCE]) AS DateInBinary
FROM UFO_MERGED
```

Depending on your encoding you may get a result like this `0x352f31352f32303036`
You can look up the values to see what character you are pulling. Mine matches this page
https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm
so '5' = 35 and '/' = 2f, etc.

Once you find the binary value you may use replace as you have before `REPLACE([SECOND OCCURANCE],CHAR(<binary value>),'')` Then try to catch where the bad data gets mixed into your records.

Comment: the datatype of this field is varchar(11)

Comment: I have tried converting date2 to datetime using convert(datetime,date2,101)

Comment: i get this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string –

Answer (score 0):

You could try by using `LTRIM` + `RTRIM`.

`TRIM` function is available on SQL Server 2017:

```
select top(5)
       [SECOND OCCURANCE] as [Date 2]
       ,len([SECOND OCCURANCE]) as [CharDate2]
       ,len([LTRIM(RTRIM(SECOND OCCURANCE]))) as [NewCharDate2]
       ,[Second Occurance] = case when len([SECOND OCCURANCE]) = 10 
                                  then(right(CONCAT('0',[SECOND OCCURANCE]),11)) 
                                  else [SECOND OCCURANCE] end
from UFO_MERGED
```

Comment: Just `RTRIM()` is likely enough in this case.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn REPLACE removes trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: @McNets Hi, the output is same even using LTRIM and RTRIM. I have tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this:

```
select top(5)
   '"' + [SECOND OCCURANCE] + '"' as [raw]
  ,len([SECOND OCCURANCE]) as [rawLen]
  ,'"' + ltrim(rtrim([SECOND OCCURANCE])) + '"' as [rawTrim]
  ,len(ltrim(rtrim([SECOND OCCURANCE])) as [rawTrimLen]
from UFO_MERGED
```

That will give you information about your data. It's likely you have some control characters in there.

Use something like this to find the control characters and replace them with `''` (empty string):

```
declare @s varchar(10) = 'Hogan ' + char(9) + ' ';
select '"' + @s + '"' as raw
     , convert(varbinary, @s) as rawHex
     , '"' + ltrim(rtrim(@s)) + '"' as trim 
     , convert(varbinary, ltrim(rtrim(@s))) as trimHex
```