# Identifying values that have a space

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have some data in one of our database table, the structure of which is something like this.

```
ID      NAME
1002    Total Cost         
1003    Market Price       
1004    Total Cost         
1005    Total Cost         
1006    Sales Price        
1007    Gross Price        
1008    Gross Price
```

In our UI, we have a page where we see the distinct Names from the above table. The problem is that for 'Total Cost', we see two records - one by the name 'Total Cost' and another by the name 'Total Cost ' (i.e with one extra space at the end). I'm unable to identify where the extra space is.

I see 3 records always When I execute the below query, with no matter how many extra trailing spaces.

```
SELECT * FROM AB_MASTER_DATA WHERE NAME LIKE '%Total Cost   %'
```

How can I identify the bad data?

We are using MS SQL 2014.

Comment: Look up LTRIM and RTRIM

Comment: you may have to check for trailing control characters  ie char(10),char(13) etc.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Comment: @dfundako why? Doesn't affect uniqueness...

Comment: Depends on what you consider "bad data".   What result are you trying to get exactly?

Answer (score 2):

- You're assuming it's a space
- Trailing spaces don't affect uniqueness therefore **any solution with TRIM fails**

So the string `Total Cost` won't be affected by normal spaces

However, there are "other spaces": TAB, hard space, CR, LF etc
And we've not even using [nvarchar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) yet

Example with UNIQUE constraint on the Name columns

```
DECLARE @UniqueTest table (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    UniqueName varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

--OK so far
INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Market Price')
INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Total Cost')

--gives error
--INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Total Cost     ') 

--tab
INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Total' + CHAR(9) + 'Cost')
--hard space
INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Total' + CHAR(160) + 'Cost')
-- TRAILING CR
INSERT @UniqueTest VALUES ('Total Cost' + CHAR(13))

SELECT * FROM @UniqueTest
```

To find rows that **aren't** simple alphanumeric or spaces

```
SELECT * FROM @UniqueTest WHERE UniqueName LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Your UI, where you are adding data.
You should TRIM your data if you want to be secure about trailing and ending spaces. But also you can have issues with Upper/Lowercase strings, so you have to manage this also.
Also you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM AB_MASTER_DATA WHERE TRIM(NAME) LIKE 'Total Cost'
```

To select only one from all that satisfy the condition:

Answer (score 0):

Trailing spaces, as you've found out, are ignored in string comparisons in SQL. This is part of the SQL standard. If you want to find trailing spaces you can do something like:

```
WHERE CONCAT(NAME, '<') LIKE '%Total Cost <'
```

The point being to concatenate some character after the trailing spaces, so they are no longer ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the records using:

```
where name like 'Total Cost_%'
```

`'_'` is a wildcard that matches any character, but requires a character to be there.

You can identify the character (if it is ASCII) by doing something like:

```
select ascii(substring(name, 11, 1))
```