# Determine what unprintable character(s) are in a SQL column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL returns a single row.

```
select subjectname, 
       comments 
  from vad_comments
where SurveyDetailRowId = 8075175
```

[image: One Row Qualifies]

It appears as though the comments column is blank. Either all spaces, or empty string. (It's not NULL because SSMS shows NULL values specifically as NULL).

So let's try this -

```
select subjectname, 
       comments 
  from vad_comments
where SurveyDetailRowId = 8075175
  and rtrim(ltrim(Comments)) = ''
```

[image: No Rows Qualify]

But now the row vanishes! Whatever is in that column doesn't get trimmed so it's not null, it's not empty string and it's not spaces. Obviously, there must be some unprintable characters in there. Short of writing a software client to pull the value and interrogate its binary representation, is there anything I can do at the SQL level to determine what characters are occupying that column?

And just to remove any ambiguity:

[image: Selecting for NULL]

So it's not NULL, it's not empty string and it's not space(s). Can you help me find out what's in that column?

Comment: It obviously has a hidden character (or more). `ASCII(LEFT(Comments,1))` would tell you what the first character is. Could be many. Line break, carriage return. Zero-width space, the list goes on.

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents of the **comments** to a text editor that allows you to show non-printing characters (e.g. Notepad++)?

Comment: I'm sure it is just a matter of CRLF, but if you are looking for something more robust, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Comment: "Short of writing a software client to pull the value and interrogate its binary representation" - can you just do `select cast(comments as varbinary(max))` and take a look at what it comes back with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several characters that it could be, from my own experience i have found none breaking space(CHAR(160)) to be a common issue if data is copied from a web page.

You can find the characters using the following script:

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(100) = CHAR(160) + '123 ABC';
WITH 
    Numbers(Number) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 AS Number
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT
            Number + 1
        FROM
            Numbers
        WHERE Number < 100
    )
SELECT
    Number AS [CharIndex],
    SUBSTRING(@Text, Number, 1) AS [Character],
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Text, Number, 1)) AS AsciiCode
FROM 
    Numbers
WHERE
    Number <= LEN(@Text);
```

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or higher you can use the trim function to remove the characters:

```
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(32)+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(160) FROM @TEXT)
```

Comment: Brilliant! I am using Azure SQL Server so I am able to use the TRIM syntax which you propose. Here it is (sorry, I can't include the carriage returns). select subjectname, 
       comments 
  from vad_comments
where SurveyDetailRowId = 8075175
  and TRIM(CHAR(32)+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(160) FROM Comments) = ''